# Display random div according to their data-role with jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm actually building a web application using jQuery Mobile. I have pages full of elements with specials `data-role` and I would like to randomly display some of these `div` on the homepage according to their `data-role`.

Is it possble? If it is, does some of you know how to do that ?

HTML :

```
<div id="home" data-role="page" data-theme="b">
    <div class="content" data-role="content"> </div></div>
```

Elements of pages in my HTML file:

```
  <div data-role="place">
       <h1 class="blue">Ballymastocker's beach</h1>
        <p>Ballymastocker, Fanad, Co. Donegal, Ireland. <br/> </p>

       <a href="#gmap"><img src="img/exploring/lakes-beaches/ballymastocker1.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">Read More</a><br/><br/>
    </div>

     <div data-role="place">
          <h1 class="blue">Coral beach</h1>
          <p>Coral beach, Saint John's point, Co. Donegal, Ireland. <br/> </p>
        <a href="#gmap"><img src="img/exploring/lakes-beaches/coralbeach1.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">Read More</a><br/><br/>
     </div>


     <div data-role="place">       
         <h1 class="blue">Dunfanhagy's beach</h1>
            <p>Dunfanhagy, Co. Donegal, Ireland. <br/> </p>
           <a href="#gmap"><img src="img/exploring/lakes-beaches/dunfanhagy1.jpg" /></a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">Read More</a><br/><br/>
      </div>
```

I used the Js script as you provide me below :

```
$( "div[data-role='place']" ).each(function( home ) {
   if ( Math.random() < 0.5 ) $( this ).hide();
});
```

But nothing happend. Some one know why ?

Check it out [here](http://multiclics.fr/app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( "div[data-role]" ).each(function( index ) {
   if ( Math.random() < 0.5 ) $( this ).hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but nothing happend, i updated my post and provide some codes for you. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: The problem is that the div with data-role="place" are not on the home page but somewhere else (in the same file)